# Variance of Autocorrelated Error

Tags: regression, time-series, variance, autocorrelation

I'm following along this course notes: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/lesson/14/14.2

Here, it states the following(roughly)

Consider the following situation where the model is

$$y_t = X_t \beta + \epsilon_t$$

and there is auto-correlation between the errors, that is

$$\epsilon_t = \rho \epsilon_{t-1} + w_t$$

where $w_t ~ N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $\left| \rho \right| < 1$

It states without proof that

$$Var(\epsilon_t) = \frac{\sigma^2}{1-\rho^2}$$

But I don't know where the variance comes from.

The way I'm thinking,

$$Var(\epsilon_1) = Var(w_1) = \sigma^2$$

$$Var(\epsilon_2) = Var(\rho \epsilon_1 + w_2) = Var(\rho w_1 + w_2) = \rho^2 Var(w_1) + Var(w_2) = \rho^2\sigma^2 + \sigma^2$$

$$Var(\epsilon_3) = Var(\rho \epsilon_2 + w_3) = Var(\rho(\rho \epsilon_1 + w_2) + w_3) =Var(\rho(\rho w_1 + w_2) + w_3) = \rho^4 \sigma^2 + \rho^2 \sigma^2 + \sigma^2 $$

and so on.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\operatorname{var}(\epsilon_t)&=\operatorname{cov}(\epsilon_t,\epsilon_t)=\operatorname{cov}(\rho\epsilon_{t-1}+w_t,\rho\epsilon_{t-1}+w_t)\\&=\operatorname{cov}(\rho\epsilon_{t-1},\rho\epsilon_{t-1})+\overbrace{\operatorname{cov}(\rho\epsilon_{t-1},w_t)}^0+\overbrace{\operatorname{cov}(w_t,\rho\epsilon_{t-1})}^0+\operatorname{cov}(w_t,w_t)\\&=\rho^2\operatorname{var}(\epsilon_{t-1})+\sigma^2\\&=\rho^2\operatorname{var}(\epsilon_{t})+\sigma^2\end{align}$$

which means $$\operatorname{var}(\epsilon_{t})={\sigma^2 \over {1-\rho^2}}$$

Comment: how do you go from var(e_{t-1}) = var(e_{t})? Sorry, very much new to this subject.

Comment: although not explicitly stated, AR(1) model is wide-sense stationary when $|\rho|<1$, which means the mean is constant, and autocovariance of $\epsilon_t, \epsilon_{t-\tau}$ only depends on the time lag, $\tau$. So, the variance doesn't depend on $t$.

Comment: is AR(1) being wide-sense stationary something that is assumed or something that can be proved? @gunes

Comment: @Phil it's not assumed. In AR(p), if all the roots of the characteristic equation are inside the unit circle, i.e. here just $\rho$, the series is WSS. Check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model

Answer (score 0):

The variance of can be found as:

\begin{align}
&\gamma_0 = var(\rho\epsilon_{t_1} + w_t) \\
& \gamma_0 = \rho^2\gamma_0 + \sigma^2 \\
& \gamma_0(1 - \rho^2) = \sigma^2 \\
& \gamma_0 = \frac{\sigma^2}{(1-\rho^2)}
\end{align}